# How to get table names from SQL query?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to get all the tables names from a sql query in Spark using Scala.

Lets say user sends a SQL query which looks like:

```
select * from table_1 as a left join table_2 as b on a.id=b.id
```

I would like to get all tables list like `table_1` and `table_2`.

Is regex the only option ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks a lot @Swapnil Chougule for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50833051/1305344). That inspired me to offer an idiomatic way of collecting all the tables in a structured query.

```
scala> spark.version
res0: String = 2.3.1

def getTables(query: String): Seq[String] = {
  val logicalPlan = spark.sessionState.sqlParser.parsePlan(query)
  import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedRelation
  logicalPlan.collect { case r: UnresolvedRelation => r.tableName }
}

val query = "select * from table_1 as a left join table_2 as b on a.id=b.id"
scala> getTables(query).foreach(println)
table_1
table_2
```

Comment: can the same functionality be achieved in pyspark?

Comment: This is not complete, tables in CTE are ignored, "WIth" type's children needs to be visited additionally

Comment: @smokeny Can you show the query that breaks the code? That'd be super helpful.

Comment: As simple as 
`with e as (select * from temp.tbl3),
d as (select * from temp.tbl1)
select * from (
select * from temp.tbl1 a cross join temp.tbl2 b) c cross join d cross join e`. Your snippet will skip temp.tbl3 and temp.tbl3

Comment: Since sessionState has a private access in Spark 2.4.4, what would be the preferred way to achieve the same in Spark 2.4.4?

Comment: @AnantKumar Just checked that out in 2.4.4 and `spark.sessionState.sqlParser` worked just fine. What's the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 8):

Hope it will help you

Parse the given query using spark sql parser (spark internally does same). You can get sqlParser from session's state. It will give Logical plan of query. Iterate over logical plan of query & check whether it is instance of UnresolvedRelation (leaf logical operator to represent a table reference in a logical query plan that has yet to be resolved) & get table from it.

```
def getTables(query: String) : Seq[String] ={
    val logical : LogicalPlan = localsparkSession.sessionState.sqlParser.parsePlan(query)
    val tables = scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet.empty[String]
    var i = 0
    while (true) {
      if (logical(i) == null) {
        return tables.toSeq
      } else if (logical(i).isInstanceOf[UnresolvedRelation]) {
        val tableIdentifier = logical(i).asInstanceOf[UnresolvedRelation].tableIdentifier
        tables += tableIdentifier.unquotedString.toLowerCase
      }
      i = i + 1
    }
    tables.toSeq
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some complicated sql queries with nested queries and iterated on @Jacek Laskowski's answer to get this

```
  def getTables(spark: SparkSession, query: String): Seq[String] = {
    val logicalPlan = spark.sessionState.sqlParser.parsePlan(query)
    var tables = new ListBuffer[String]()
    var i: Int = 0

    while (logicalPlan(i) != null) {
      logicalPlan(i) match {
        case t: UnresolvedRelation => tables += t.tableName
        case _ => 
      }
      i += 1
    }

    tables.toList
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def __sqlparse2table(self, query):
    '''
    @description: get table name from table
    '''
    plan = self.spark._jsparkSession.sessionState().sqlParser().parsePlan(query)
    plan_string = plan.toString().replace('`.`', '.')
    unr = re.findall(r"UnresolvedRelation `(.*?)`", plan_string)
    cte = re.findall(r"CTE \[(.*?)\]", plan.toString())
    cte = [tt.strip() for tt in cte[0].split(',')] if cte else cte
    schema = set()
    tables = set()
    for table_name in unr:
        if table_name not in cte:
            schema.update([table_name.split('.')[0]])
            tables.update([table_name])

    return schema, tables
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you need to list all the columns names listed in table1 and table2, what you can do is to show tables in db.table_name in your hive db.

```
val tbl_column1 = sqlContext.sql("show tables in table1");
val tbl_column2 = sqlContext.sql("show tables in table2");
```

You will get list of columns in both the table.

tbl_column1.show

```
name      
id  
data
```

Comment: grep 'overwrite table' *.txt | sed -r 's/.*?(overwrite table)\s`?([^` ]*).*/\2/g' | sort -u  , UNIX did the trick

Comment: grep 'INTO\|FROM\|JOIN' *.sql | sed -r 's/.*?(FROM|INTO|JOIN)\s`?([^` ]*).*/\2/g' | sort -u

Answer (score -4):

unix did the trick, grep 'INTO\|FROM\|JOIN' *.sql | sed -r 's/.*?(FROM|INTO|JOIN)\s`?([^` ]*).*/\2/g' | sort -u

grep 'overwrite table' .txt | sed -r 's/.?(overwrite table)\s?([^ ]*).*/\2/g' | sort -u