# Importing spark.sql.catalyst library in spark

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to find a way to interpret the table names from spark sql.
The answer given here is in Scala [How to get table names from SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785796/how-to-get-table-names-from-sql-query/50833051#50833051)

I want to change this into pyspark.

For that I want to import the library 
`org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedRelation` (or its equivalent) into pyspark.

Can this be done?

Comment: This is before executing the query? If not, you can always use `spark.catalog.listTables()` to get the Tables available in your current `SparkSession`

Comment: yes , I have to retrieve the table names before executing the query